# Why does this calculation result in this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The following basis is given to me: 
$|L\rangle = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       \\
    0       
\end{bmatrix}$

$|R\rangle = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0       \\
    1       
\end{bmatrix}$

and I am told that

$(|LL\rangle \langle LL| + |RR\rangle \langle RR|)$=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

I guess that if $|L\rangle = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       \\
    0       
\end{bmatrix}$ then

$\langle L| = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0              
\end{bmatrix}$, same for $R$

Could someone explain to me how they got that matrix ?

Comment: The $|LL\rangle$ notation is likely the tensor product: $|LL\rangle=|L\rangle\otimes|L\rangle$. That's the piece you're missing, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $|LL\rangle$ denotes the tensor product $|L\rangle\otimes |L\rangle$, which we can compute the matrix form of by using the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Using this allows you to compute the expressions for $|LL\rangle$ and $|RR\rangle$, where $\langle LL|$ and $\langle RR|$ are the transposes as you mentioned in your question. Then just compute to get the matrix.